# Parse partially match an array in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a search bar in my app, and the items it searches from in Parse has an attribute "searchTokens" in my DB, which is compiled from a couple different attributes of that item.

However, when searching, the only way I can see to match items is the following:

```
query?.whereKey("searchTokens", containsAllObjectsIn: keywords)
```

The problem is, this only returns item where every keyword has a match, not any keyword.

I don't see any other Parse functions that could achieve this, nor do I know how to do it myself some other way.

Ideas?

Edit:
My comment to an answer that someone posted that I think adds a little clarity?:

Ah, so, Parse is a backend as a service based on mongoDB, it's not local. The query? you see in my post is a PFQuery type. The containsAllObjectsIn is a function that takes a list of objects (hence the keywords in my code above being plural; and in this instance matches strings) and matches all the keywords to the array found for the "column" in my "table" that is a list of search words/tokens that have relevance to that entry.

Answer (score 0):

this extension would help

```
extension String{
    func containsIgnoringCase(find: String) -> Bool{
        //next two line might be necessary if you are using special language other than english
        //let locale = Locale.init(identifier: $language identifier$)
        //let temp = self.lowercased(with: locale)
        return self.range(of: find, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil

    }
}
```

If I get right, take your database list and filter with this method like

```
let newList = yourlist.filter{$0.containsIgnoringCase(find: $search key$)}
```

Comment: Ah, so, Parse is a backend as a service based on mongoDB, it's not local.  The query? you see in my post is a PFQuery<PFObject> type.  The containsAllObjectsIn is a function that takes a list of objects (hence the keywords in my code above being plural; and in this instance matches strings) and matches all the keywords to the array found for the "column" in my "table" that is a list of search words/tokens that have relevance to that entry.